# How fancy text generators copy fancy text in clipboard while Clipboard only copies plain text and loses details about text font?

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, clipboarddata

I have been searching here and there about how to copy fancy text in clipboard programmatically, but it only copies plain text. Android experts on various forums are saying this is not possible but then how Fancy Fonts apps on play store copy those fancy words in clipboard?

I tried setting custom font to TextView then copy that text and font details were lost. So this mean the font attribute was set for TextView only not the actual text so how can I apply font to actual text?

Comment: At a guess, Fancy Fonts doesn't use different fonts, but uses different Unicode codepoints that to your eye seem to be the same character, but in a different font, while in reality it is a different character with its own glyph in the same font.